# Jekyll error: Invalid assignment

Tags: jekyll

All of the sudden I experience an error I can not debug.

```
JS_Parse_Error.get ((execjs):3538:621): SyntaxError: Invalid assignment (ExecJS::RuntimeError)
from (execjs):4060:47
from (execjs):1:102
from Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:120)
from Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
from Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
from Module.load (module.js:503:32)
from tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
from Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
from Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:195:in `run_uglifyjs'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:157:in `compile'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-minifier-0.1.5/lib/jekyll-minifier.rb:53:in `output_js'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-minifier-0.1.5/lib/jekyll-minifier.rb:123:in `write'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:212:in `block in write'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:333:in `block (2 levels) in each_site_file'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:332:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:332:in `block in each_site_file'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:331:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:331:in `each_site_file'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:211:in `write'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `process'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:26:in `process_site'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:63:in `build'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:34:in `process'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in init_with_program'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:40:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/exe/jekyll:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

I'm wondering whether has solved this error?

UPDATE:

I have updated the libs along the way. Here the GIT diff from the Gemfile.lock

```
  -    addressable (2.5.1)
  -    public_suffix (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.2)
  +    addressable (2.5.2)
  +    public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
  -    jekyll (3.5.0)
  +    jekyll (3.5.2)
  -    jekyll-minifier (0.1.4)
  +    jekyll-minifier (0.1.5)
  -    kramdown (1.14.0)
  +    kramdown (1.15.0)
  -    pathutil (0.14.0)
  +    pathutil (0.16.0)
  -    public_suffix (2.0.5)
  +    public_suffix (3.0.0)
  -    sass (3.5.1)
  +    sass (3.5.2)
  -  jekyll (= 3.5)
  +  jekyll (= 3.5.2)

BUNDLED WITH
  -   1.14.6
  +   1.15.4
```

I'm wondering whether something went wrong with the update?

Comment: Do you have JavaScript anywhere in your project? And is the project under version control (e.g. with Git)?

Comment: Yes, I have few JS libs (JQuery, Bootstrap ect) and the project is under version control (GIT)

Comment: Can you use Git to compare the last working version against the broken one and post the diff?

Comment: I could not find anything suspicious :-(

Comment: *Post the diff*

Comment: Use the [edit] link to add the information to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone else gets the same error, I had a `test.js` file in the root directory of the project where I was playing around with some JS functions. The content looks something like that:

```
const applyOffset = (offsetX, offsetY) => {
  let counterX = 0
  let counterY = 0
  $(".blogPost").each((key, value) => {
    let offsetXTotal = offsetX * counterX
    let offsetYTotal = offsetY * counterY
    // change the transform value
    $("#" + value.id).css({
        transform: "translate3d(" + offsetXTotal + "px," + offsetYTotal + "px, 0)"
    })
    if(counterX < 2) {
        counterX++
    } else {
        counterX = 0
        counterY++
    }
  })
}
```

This file caused Jekyll's compiler to throw an exception. After deleting this file I was able to start the server.

[@Rian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan) was right with his first question whether I have a JS file.

**Another lesson learned!**

Comment: You can also add it to `exclude` in `_config.yml`